# Batch replace with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replace

I was wondering how to go replacing a series of strings in batch. For example if I wanted to remove full stops from a field and also change double spaces between characters into single spaces. I know using Python one can simply use something like:
 .replace('.','').replace('  ', ' ').replace(etc.). Using postgresql it would look more like

```
UPDATE table
SET field = replace(field, 'replace text','replacement text')
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work for multiple replacement options. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE()` function multiple times like

```
UPDATE table
SET field = replace(replace(field, '.',''),'  ',' ')
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, that was what I was looking for, I'm very new to postgres and tried a series of replace functions outside of the parens and it failed.